# Filter multi fasta file with matching ID string between specific symbols

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I got stuck over this problem for a while and although I found a diverse set of similar questions none exactly fitted my problem or solved the issue. So here is the deal:

I have an `input.fasta` , formatted like this:

```
>sp|O42363|APOA1_DANRE Apolipoprotein A-I OS=Danio rerio OX=7955 GN=apoa1 PE=2 SV=1
MKFVALALTLLLALGSQANLFQADAPTQLEHYKAAALVYLNQVKDQAEKALDNLDGTDYEQYKLQLSESLTKLQEYAQTTSQALTPYAETISTQLMENTKQLRERVMTDVEDLRSKLEPHRAELYTALQKHIDEYREKLEPVFQEYSALNRQNAEQLRAKLEPLMDDIRKAFESNIEETKSKVVPMVEAVRTKLTERLEDLRTMAAPYAEEYKEQLVKAVEEAREKIAPHTQDLQTRMEPYMENVRTTFAQMYETIAKAIQA
>sp|Q90260|ASL1B_DANRE Achaete-scute homolog 1b OS=Danio rerio OX=7955 GN=ascl1b PE=2 SV=1
MEATVVATTQLTQDSFYQPFSESLEKQDRECKVLKRQRSSSPELLRCKRRLTFNGLGYTIPQQQPMAVARRNERERNRVKQVNMGFQTLRQHVPNGAANKKMSKVETLRSAVEYIRALQQLLDEHDAVSAVLQCGVPSPSVSNAYSAGPESPHSAYSSDEGSYEHLSSEEQELLDFTTWFDRYESGASMATKDWC
>sp|Q6TH01|C10_DANRE Protein C10 OS=Danio rerio OX=7955 GN=si:dkey-29f10.1 PE=2 SV=1
MASAPAQQPTLTVEQARVVLSEVIQAFSVPENAARMEEARESACNDMGKMLQLVLPVATQIQQEVIKAYGFNNEGEGVLKFARLVKMYETQDPEIAAMSVKLKSLLLPPLSTPPIGSGIPTS
>sp|Q6PFL6|CCD43_DANRE Coiled-coil domain-containing protein 43 OS=Danio rerio OX=7955 GN=ccdc43 PE=2 SV=1
MAAPEQIAGEFENWLNERLDSLEVDREVYGAYILGVLQEEESDEEQKDALQGILSAFLEEETLEEVCQEILKQWTECCSRSGAKSNQADAEVQAIASLIEKQAQIVVKQKEVSEDAKKRKEAVLAQYANVTDDEDEAEEEEQVPVGIPSDKSLFKNTNVEDVLNRRKLQRDQAKEDAQKKKEQDKMQREKDKLSKQERKDKEKKRTQKGERKR
>sp|P0C7U5|C5AR1_DANRE C5a anaphylatoxin chemotactic receptor 1 OS=Danio rerio OX=7955 GN=c5ar1 PE=3 SV=1
MDDNNSDWTSYDFGNDTIPSPNEISLSHIGTRHWITLVCYGIVFLLGVPGNALVVWVTGFRMPNSVNAQWFLNLAIADLLCCLSLPILMVPLAQDQHWPFGALACKLFSGIFYMMMYCSVLLLVVISLDRFLLVTKPVWCQNNRQPRQARILCFIIWILGLLGSSPYFAHMEIQHHSETKTVCTGSYSSLGHAWAITIIRSFLFFLLPFLIICISHWKVYHMTSSGRRQRDKSSRTLRVILALVLGFFLCWTPLH
```

and an `ids.txt` list, formatted as this:

```
Q90260
Q6PFL6
```

I would like to extract all fasta sequences with their header for which the IDs of `ids.txt` are element of the header.
I have tried `grep -w -A 2 -Ff  id_list.txt input.fasta --no-group-separator > out.fasta` but that did not work.

Ideally, I would like to express via regex to check if the string between the two `|` of each line starting with `>sp` matches any ID in my `idx.txt`. And if so, to store that header and fasta in `out.fasta`.

So that `out.fasta` would look like that:

```
>sp|Q90260|ASL1B_DANRE Achaete-scute homolog 1b OS=Danio rerio OX=7955 GN=ascl1b PE=2 SV=1
MEATVVATTQLTQDSFYQPFSESLEKQDRECKVLKRQRSSSPELLRCKRRLTFNGLGYTIPQQQPMAVARRNERERNRVKQVNMGFQTLRQHVPNGAANKKMSKVETLRSAVEYIRALQQLLDEHDAVSAVLQCGVPSPSVSNAYSAGPESPHSAYSSDEGSYEHLSSEEQELLDFTTWFDRYESGASMATKDWC
>sp|Q6PFL6|CCD43_DANRE Coiled-coil domain-containing protein 43 OS=Danio rerio OX=7955 GN=ccdc43 PE=2 SV=1
MAAPEQIAGEFENWLNERLDSLEVDREVYGAYILGVLQEEESDEEQKDALQGILSAFLEEETLEEVCQEILKQWTECCSRSGAKSNQADAEVQAIASLIEKQAQIVVKQKEVSEDAKKRKEAVLAQYANVTDDEDEAEEEEQVPVGIPSDKSLFKNTNVEDVLNRRKLQRDQAKEDAQKKKEQDKMQREKDKLSKQERKDKEKKRTQKGERKR
```

I am pretty sure this can be expressed via `awk` or `grep` but I am new to bash so I am having a hard time right now.

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'[|]' 'NR==FNR{ids[$0];next}$2 in ids' ids.txt input.fasta
```

**Explanation:**

I'm passing both files ids.txt and input.fasta as input files to awk. The order is important. `-F'[|]'` sets the input field delimiter to a `|`.

The script:

```
# NR  is the overall record (line) number
# FNR is the record (line) number in the current input file

NR==FNR {   # True as long as we are reading the first input file
    ids[$0]   # Create a key in ids for every id from ids.txt
    next      # Don't process further actions
}

# Because of the 'next' statement above, we'll reach this point only
# when reading the second input file (input.fasta)
$2 in ids   # Print the current line if the second field
            # was found in the ids lookup
```

**Output:**

```
>sp|Q90260|ASL1B_DANRE Achaete-scute homolog 1b OS=Danio rerio OX=7955 GN=ascl1b PE=2 SV=1
>sp|Q6PFL6|CCD43_DANRE Coiled-coil domain-containing protein 43 OS=Danio rerio OX=7955 GN=ccdc43 PE=2 SV=1
```

---

Update: It turned out that you also want to print the below the match. This can be achieved like this:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[|]"
}

# NR  is the overall record (line) number
# FNR is the record (line) number in the current input file

NR==FNR {   # True as long as we are reading the first input file
    ids[$0]   # Create a key in ids for every id from ids.txt
    next      # Don't process further actions
}

# Because of the 'next' statement above, we'll reach this point only
# when reading the second input file (input.fasta)
$2 in ids  {
    # set or reset a variable p to 2 if the second field
    # was found in the ids lookup
    p = 2
}

# Decrement the variable p on every iteration and check if it
# is greater than 0 after that. If that's true, awk will print 
# the current line
p--> 0
```

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. The output is very close to what I need but it still misses the fasta sequence (line below the header).  I tried something less specific and it seems to work now: `grep -A1 -F -f ids.txt input.fasta | sed '/-$/d' > out.fasta`
Before I ran that line I converted the `ids.txt` with `dos2unix`. After that it did work. I assume that the `ids.txt` was probably generated on a windows system and was not compatible for unix.

Comment: Hey, sorry, didn't understand this requirement. The following awk command will print the line below the header too: `awk -F'[|]' 'NR==FNR{ids[$0];next}$2 in ids{p=2}p>0;{p--}' ids.txt input.fasta` (will add to my answer later)

Comment: Works great! :) Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome. updated the answer and added an explanation

Answer (score 2):

Using `join` and `sort`:

```
join -t \| -2 2 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3 <(sort ids.txt) <(sort -t \| -k2 input.fasta)
```

Assuming there is no extra `|` character in the input.fasta and the order of output lines isn't significant.